# Creating a New React App Takes Hours Without Success

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using Windows 10 and I have Node.js v12.14.1 and npm 6.13.4.

I tried `npx create-react-app my-app` and `npm init react-app my-app`

Both took forever without creating the app.

All I could see was

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
```

After that nothing showed up in the command line.

But it does create tons of files, I was able to see `node_modules` folder and `package.json`. Deleting those thousands of files also took a long time...

How can I solve this problem? I also tried `npm cache clean --force` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the packages using `npm uninstall - create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

To create a new app, you may choose one of the following methods:

**npx**

`npx create-react-app my-app`

**npm**

`npm init react-app my-app`

**Yarn**

`yarn create react-app my-app`

It automatically installs node_modules and it is fine to show this log on the terminal.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
```

Best,